# Reassign a value in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Following is the values.yaml in helm chart:

```
global:
  namespace: istio
chart-1:
  istioNamespace: istio
chart-2:
  targetNamespace: istio
```

Is there a way where `istioNamespace` and `targetNamespace` can refer global.namespace?

Comment: Do you control the subcharts `chart-1` and `chart-2`?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a YAML, you can make use of its anchor, aliases, merge keys to re-use the values/data.DIY.

In your case, you could do something like this:
In the YAML Document, you can refer to a previously defined anchor with an alias

```
global:
  namespace: &ns "istio"
chart-1:
  istioNamespace: *ns
chart-2:
  targetNamespace: *ns
```

**NOTE: if you try to override this with other `values.yaml` that might not work as expected.
This is useful when you are doing it in the same YAML file.**

[Here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2019/05/reusing-data-with-yaml-anchors-aliases-and-merge-keys.html) is a reference link. and in [official docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#yaml-anchors) as well.

I have tried a few of them in my day to day works with helm charts, and they work pretty well with `Values. yaml`